# CStatic.setBitmap is causing the rectangle to flicker (MFC) in onpaint

Tags: c++, mfc, paint

I am trying to refresh an image relatively quickly (like 10fps) and and it flashes every couple frames. I have narrowed down the area that the flashes occurs to the place where I am setting the bitmap to the `CStatic` in my `OnPaint`.

The code looks like:

```
void CRadarView::OnPaint()
{

    CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

    if (m_streaming == -1 || m_frameThread.fgArr.size() == 0 || m_frameThread.bgArr.size() == 0 || m_frameThread.subtractedFgArr.size() == 0)
        return;


    CDC *screenDC = GetDC();
    CDC mDC;
    mDC.CreateCompatibleDC(screenDC);
    CMemDC memDC(*screenDC, this);
    CDC& rDC = memDC.GetDC();

    // Raw radar image
    //-----------------

    if (m_showRadar)
    {
        CBitmap b1;
        CImage img1;
        getImage(img1, m_frameThread.fgArr);
        b1.CreateCompatibleBitmap(&rDC, m_imageDisplaySize.x, m_imageDisplaySize.y);

        CBitmap *pob1 = rDC.SelectObject(&b1);
        rDC.SetStretchBltMode(HALFTONE);
        if (zoomed){
            img1.StretchBlt(rDC, 0, 0, m_imageDisplaySize.x, m_imageDisplaySize.y, zoomXStart, zoomYStart, zoomXEnd - zoomXStart, zoomYEnd - zoomYStart, SRCCOPY);
        }
        else{
            img1.StretchBlt(rDC, 0, 0, m_imageDisplaySize.x, m_imageDisplaySize.y, 0, 0, img1.GetWidth(), img1.GetHeight(), SRCCOPY);
        }

        rDC.SelectObject(pob1);
        m_image.SetBitmap((HBITMAP)b1); //THIS IS WHERE THE FLASHING IS OCCURING
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't set the static bitmap in `OnPaint()`, because this will generate another `WM_PAINT` message which you notice as flickering.

Comment: Hmm what else can I use? I'm sorry if its a dumb question, I am really new to MFC and kinda got thrown into it alone.

Comment: Can't say without knowing more about the code. How do you get notified of new frames currently?

Comment: I have a timer and I invalidateRect(NULL,false) in the ontimer event

Comment: Assign the bitmap to the static in the timer handler. `InvalidateRect` shouldn't be necessary. If at all, you should call it on the static only.

Comment: In the past, I found it easiest to just create my own window class to handle bitmap drawing. The static control never did exactly what I wanted.

Comment: so I tried to move it to my timer thing but for some reason its making like the whole window go black right after the image gets set. So the static gets setup, shows for a split second and then the whole window goes black each frame. Also I must say I'm not entirely sure I have time to write a whole window class and am also prob not comfortable enough with MFC to actually accomplish that tbh.

Comment: A third way would be to get rid of the static and just do all drawing in `CRadarView::OnPaint()`. I mean you already have a `CImage` and you could just do `CImage::BitBlt(dc, ...)` to paint it onto the view.

Comment: If I was to do that   ```mg1.BitBlt(rDC, m_rectRaw.left, m_rectFod.top, m_rectRaw.right - m_rectRaw.left, m_rectRaw.bottom - m_rectRaw.top, src, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);``` what would be the src context?

Comment: The `CImage` creates its own src DC on demand.

Comment: ahh okay so I got it sort of working just not in the correct location. Thank you so much for your help!